# Intent to Pebble app store

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, pebble-watch

**Is it possible to redirect the user of my app to my watchface entry in the recently released Pebble store, from my Android app?**

Technically, I was wondering if the new 2.0.0 Pebble app catches any `URI`s or `Intent`s in order to let the user land on an specific entry in the Pebble store, just like we can redirect users to a Play Store entry via `market:details?id=xyz` or even `https://play.google.com/apps/details?id=xyz` `URI`s.

Does it expose similar functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use pebble://appstore/APP_ID where APP_ID is the Pebble appstore ID of your app, which you can find by going the developer portal, going into the details for your app, and it's the last part of the URL.

It doesn't work properly at the moment with the current Android betas, but it will be working by the time app is released.

Comment: I should add, according to the information found on Pebble forums, that, at least for now, you should supply `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` in order for it to work. Otherwise, you may see the Pebble splash — ugh — only to go back to your `Activity`. Only after using the information in this answer and that warning I was able to successfully display my app in the Pebble store. Let's hope they fix this mistake so we can use the proper flags in the near future. :)